# What's the recommended way to load an object graph from Data Access Layer?

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design, data-access-layer, software-design

From a relatively old software architecture book:

> In other situations, the same conceptual Get-Orders query
>   might generate different data—for example, a collection of Order
>   objects plus order items information. What should you do? Should you
>   expose two slightly different GetOrders methods out of your
>   DAL? And what if, depending on the user interface, the user might ask
>   the system to return orders, order items, and products by country?
>   Will you define yet another look-alike method in the DAL?

The author suggests using Query Object pattern. Other ways I can think of:

1) Optional parameter for each relation/child collection:

```
IOrder GetOrder(int id, bool withItems = false);
```

2) Tuples

Remove IList from IOrder definition and return a tuple

```
Tuple<IOrder, IList<IOrderItems>> GetOrderWithItems(int id);
```

3) Method overloading

```
IOrder GetOrder(int id);
IOrder GetOrderWithItems(int id);
```

4) Separate methods

The DAL shouldn't deal with this.  Retrieving an order with its items should be done in two steps:

```
IOrder myOder = GetOrder(myOrderId);
myOrder.items = GetOrderItems(myOrderId);
```

What would be the best way? Another concern I have is null references. When items = null, DAL clients might confuse it for 0 (order has no items). How to deal with this?

-Convention

null = not loaded/set

empty collection  = 0 items

-Wrapper

ItemsWrapper is null: items not loaded

ItemsWrapper.items is null or (empty): 0 items

-Generics (this is probably stupid)

```
interface IOrder<TVoidableItems> where TVoidableItems : IWithoutItems
{
int id;
TVoidableItems items;
}


interface IWithoutItems{}

interface IWithItems: IWithoutItems { IList<IOrderItems> value;}
```

If the second question is off-topic, please let me know and I'll move it to a second thread. I believe it's related. Maybe I shouldn't use domain objects for the DAL in the first place and use simple relation-free types?

Comment: It seems a bit opinion-based so I will give mine. You could take a look at [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading), which is provided by most of ORMs

Comment: Which *old software architecture book* is that?

Comment: @MarkSeemann "Architecting Microsoft® .NET Solutions for the Enterprise".  Chapter 6 - The Data Access Layer. There's a second edition but it's more like a second volume and I've not read it yet.

Comment: @Cortez9 I haven't read it, so it's difficult to answer without understanding the forces and constraints leading the author to write that. Any reasoned answer in this space must start with *it depends*, but since I don't know on what it depends, I can't answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the author (Dino Esposito) is missing in [his book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735663025) is the clear separation of concerns that [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) brings. If I'm not mistaking, this pattern is completely missing from his book. In [Esposito's latest MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt147237.aspx), he explains CQRS, so I think he just wasn't that experienced at the time of writing that book. Unfortunately, the article still misses some fundamental abstractions that make query objects really powerful. [This article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) on the other hand, goes into more detail on how to model your application more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the author is assuming there's a fast track from the DB directly to the UI.

In classical domain-driven design it's not that simple, there's at least the domain layer and maybe a couple of other layers in between. In the domain model, the `Order` would (perhaps) have a list of `Items`, forming an Aggregate, but you would generate additional DTO/viewmodels/whatever from there to get something displayable in a UI.

In a DDD+CQRS context there's a quicker correpondence between database data and presentation-ready data on the read side. I would tailor my data structures to the views, which might mean two read models : `OrderWithItems` and `Order`.